# Is calling Buffer.flip() twice in a row problematic?

Tags: java

flip sets limit to position and then position to 0.

If you call flip twice, does limit get set to 0? Sometimes I don't know whether a method that takes a buffer should be responsible for flipping the buffer, or should the method caller do it. I would like to be able to call .flip in the method just incase the methodcaller did not do it. But does this cause a problem?

Comment: What `Buffer` are you referring to?

Comment: While it's a little difficult to fully understand the question, I would say, yes, it's problematic. If the state of the buffer is important to the current cycle and you flip it before it's ready, you will end up with unfinished updates. Only one part of your code should be responsible for flipping the buffer, everybody else should be focused on preparing the buffer ... I should add, you shouldn't be passing the reference of the buffer to anybody else, but should be passing the Graphics context associated with it, this means that no else cares about where the Graphics context comes from...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ByteBuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is problematic. Don't do it.

I find it's best to maintain buffers in the state where they are ready for *reading.* That way everybody knows what is expected. So, flip/get/compact or flip/write/compact should be applied very locally where it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the position and limit of a buffer to 0, then it's possible to invoke flip by twice.
But you should invoke position and limit method instead of invoking flip twice 
because to use flip, clear or rewind method is to accomplish the typical purposes and you should avoid to use this meshod unless you want to accomplish these purposes.

I cite javadoc:

Clearing, flipping, and rewinding

In addition to methods for accessing the position, limit, and capacity
 values and for marking and resetting, this class also defines the following
 operations upon buffers:

`clear()` makes a buffer ready for a new sequence of
   channel-read or relative *put* operations: It sets the limit to the
   capacity and the position to zero.

`flip()` makes a buffer ready for a new sequence of
   channel-write or relative *get* operations: It sets the limit to the
   current position and then sets the position to zero.

`rewind()` makes a buffer ready for re-reading the data that
   it already contains: It leaves the limit unchanged and sets the position
   to zero.